# WordPress Comments Order

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a reviews plugin on WordPress that uses the comments functionality to leave reviews, but these span multiple pages. Now by default WordPress places the older comments on top but I wondering if there's a way to reverse that order.

I've done some looking around and I've found that this does the trick:

```
<?php wp_list_comments(array('reverse_top_level' => false)); ?>
```

but this doesn't change the order of all the comments, it only changes the order of the comments being display on that specific page. So on the first page you have comments dating back to 2011, when I would want these to be the ones from this month.

Thanks in advanced.

Here's the site btw http://www.redbarninc.com/customer-service/customer-reviews/

Answer (score 2):

You can change this in the settings in wp-admin :)

Settings -> Discussion -> Comments should be displayed with the [older/newer] comments at the top of each page.

Comment: nvm, i just tried that and the same thing happens, the order just switches on that specific page.

Comment: The link you posted only has one page (All 16 comments are one below the other - newest first), so it's hard to see the problem. I suspect the plugin is the cause (but can't be sure) - see how it works when that is deactivated.